# time() function

Tags: php, time

[time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the

> Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

**My question is:**

1. Does it related to server time? Does output of `time();` from a server locating on UK is different from a server located on USA? Or the unix time is calculated on GMT?
2. I am calculating local time and i have gmt offsets. Do i have to add GMT offset from the unix time to find out the current local time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The Unix epoch is a fixed moment in time, not a local time, so the number of seconds since them is the same no matter where you are. Server time only affects if the server's clock is wrong :)
2. You shouldn't care about GMT offsets if the function you use to display dates is timezone aware and properly configured:

   ```
   <?php

   $now = time();

   date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
   echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s O e', $now) . PHP_EOL;

   date_default_timezone_set('America/Hermosillo');
   echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s O e', $now) . PHP_EOL;
   ```

   ... prints:

   ```
   2011-08-09 13:33:58 +0200 Europe/Madrid
   2011-08-09 04:33:58 -0700 America/Hermosillo
   ```

Answer (score 1):

As outlined at the start of [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) and in your question, the time returned is seconds since the `Unix Epoch` in **GMT**.

It is not your local time, you need to modify timezone settings or modify the value returned from `time()` to be your local time.